# No package php-opcache available

Tags: php, magento, opcache

I found so many questions here but whatever i try i always get the msg

> No package php-opcache available

i tried to follow this
http://www.unixmen.com/install-remi-repository-rhel-centos-scientific-linux-76-x5-x-fedora-201918/
then install opcache

```
# yum install php-opcache
```

but still no luck

PS: i have WHM/Cpanel installed on my AWS server and i need to install opcache for Magento

i have PHP version 5.5

```
PHP 5.5.35 (cgi-fcgi) (built: May 16 2016 18:26:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

i tried to enable it from php.ini but it says opcache.so not found 
any help would be appreciated

```
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing from Remi's repo, the name will be `php55-php-opcache`, which you could have determined from running `yum search opcache`.

But your error refers to `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so` which tells me that you have a version of PHP that was compiled from source. You need to either use packages *or* compile from source, not both. If you install from a package, things will not be put into `/usr/local/`.

Comment: well i tried yum search opcache and it says no matches found, can u please guide me or if u want provide with with step by step guide?